# Can the stirling formula be applied to any sequence of integers that tends to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example if I have $x_n=\lfloor\sqrt n \rfloor $ or $x_n =\lfloor np \rfloor $ (where $p\neq0$)

Can I apply Stirling's formula to $(x_n)$ ?

Comment: No, Stirling's formula (I assume what you meant) is only for factorials

Comment: Do you mean Stoltz?

Comment: I mean like writing $x_n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi x_n }(\frac{x_n}{e})^{x_n}$ since $x_n$ is an integer.

Comment: Writing $x_n !$ like that is fine. Stirling's formula holds (approximately) for any positive integer (or any positive real if you use the Gamma function instead of factorial)